# Spring MVC-Response is not getting from controller using angular

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am implementing simple CRUD Operation using spring restful webservices and angular js.I trying to load all the details when the page is loading.But its not getting any response.

Controller :-

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    public List<Employee> appList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    @RequestMapping(value="/employee",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loadEmployee(){
        return new ModelAndView("employee", "webemployee", new Employee());

    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/employees",method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
      public List<Employee>loadAllApps() {  
         Employee app=new Employee();
         System.out.println(".........................loadAllApps.............");
         app.setAppID("test_id");
         app.setAppName("test_name");
         appList.add(app);
       return appList;

      }
     @RequestMapping(value="/employees/insert/{appID}/{appDescr}",method = RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json")
      public List<Employee> addApps(@PathVariable String appID,@PathVariable String appDescr) throws ParseException { 
         System.out.println("appID"+appID+"appDescr..........."+appDescr);
         Employee app=new Employee();
         app.setAppID(appID);
         app.setAppName(appDescr);
         appList.add(app);
         return appList;

      } 
}
```

Jsp :-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app="AppManger">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>WebService Example</title>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<div ng-controller="appController">
<div>
<table>
    <tr  ng-repeat="app in appList">
    <td >{{ app.appID }}</td>
    <td >{{ app.appName }}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var appModule = angular.module('AppManger', []);

appModule.controller('appController', function ($scope,$http) {

    var url="http://localhost:8080/Apps";
    $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    $http.get(url+'/employee').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       alert(status);
       $scope.appList = data;
   });


});
</script>
</script>
</html>
```

when i am trying to checking status value in $http.get method.its not showing any alert message.Please let me know what issues here.

Comment: Please check the browser console log for errors. Also add a failure callback `error` to see what the error is.

Comment: Yes.Its showing "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".But i am able seen the controller System.out.println also

Comment: Your url is incorrect then. Try to directly load the data from browser, or use postman

Answer (score 0):

You seem to call your /employee endpoint but expecting a list of employees , because you assigning data response to the:

`$scope.appList = data;`

First, change that to the other endpoint you created (/employees) which returns the list.

What is the servlet-path of your mvc dispatcher servlet? This would be my first point of failure to check for. I see that you call:

`var url="http://localhost:8080/Apps";`

Does that mean that you deploy your app in context 'Apps' or is that your servlet path? If this is the context name then I assume that mvc is resolved to the 'root' path i.e. '/'. If not, check what is servlet path for the dispatcher and add that to your url (on the client side). This would explain why you get 404. 
And also, check that you can call your API directly in the browser to rule out the server-side errors as user Chandermani suggested.